# Scala -- mutually exclusive traits

Tags: scala, traits

Is there a way to define a collection of alternatives of a common type:

```
trait Mutability
trait Mutable extends Mutability
trait Immutable extends Mutability
```

and have the compiler preclude something like:

```
object Hat extends Mutable with Immutable
```

I believe I can force *some* compiler error by having a common, conflicting member but the error message is a bit oblique:

```
trait Mutability
trait Mutable extends Mutability { protected val conflict = true }
trait Immutable extends Mutability { protected val conflict = true }

object Hat extends Mutable with Immutable

<console>:10: error: object Hat inherits conflicting members:
value conflict in class Immutable$class of type Boolean  and
value conflict in class Mutable$class of type Boolean
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in object Hat.)
   object Hat extends Immutable with Mutable
```

Is there a more direct way to express this constraint and not permit someone to work around it by taking the hint offered by the compiler (override 'conflict' in Hat)?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: What goal does this achieve? I can't recall any time I've ever wanted to do this..

Comment: First, thanks for the ideas below, still mulling over whether I can get an airtight solution (that doesn't permit the all-too-easy mistake "MutabilityLevel[Mutability]" to slip through).
Second, as to the goal.  There are two levels of objective: (1) marker trait to signal handlers that they can safely not handle update events for instances of this type and (2) actually extend the Mutable trait to define those events:
class Events[T <: Mutable] {
    case class Add(T)
    case class Remove(T)
}for example.

Comment: `class Mat(name: String) extends Mutable`
`class Pat extends Immutable`

Handlers can safely assume that `object PatEvents extends Events[Pat]` cannot compile and `PatEvents.Add/Remove` do not exist

Answer (score 3):

I think this might work

```
sealed trait Mutability
case object Immutable extends Mutability
case object Mutable extends Mutability

trait MutabilityLevel[A <: Mutability]

class Foo extends MutabilityLevel[Immutable.type]
```

This (ab?)uses the fact that you can't extend the same trait twice with different parameterization

```
scala> class Foo extends MutabilityLevel[Immutable.type] with MutabilityLevel[Mutable.type]
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Foo does not conform to MutabilityLevel[Immutable.type]'s selftype MutabilityLevel[Immutable.type]
       class Foo extends MutabilityLevel[Immutable.type] with MutabilityLevel[Mutable.type]
                         ^
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Foo does not conform to MutabilityLevel[Mutable.type]'s selftype MutabilityLevel[Mutable.type]
       class Foo extends MutabilityLevel[Immutable.type] with MutabilityLevel[Mutable.type]
```

However..

```
scala> class Foo extends MutabilityLevel[Mutability]
defined class Foo
```

Comment: You could fix that by sealing `MutabilityLevel` and adding another level, e.g. `trait Immutable extends MutabilityLevel[MutabilityLevel.I]`.

Comment: @JCracknell callers could then extend Immutable and give it improper implementations.

Comment: Yes, however it would preclude the creation of a `MutabilityLevel[Mutability]`.